# Multiple Regression from data frame~!

Tags: r, regression

I'm using this dataset

```
> mtcars

make       . mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt ...
Mazda RX8   21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 ...
Mazda RX7   21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 ...
Datsun 710  22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 ...
```

Would like to do multiple regression like

```
lm(make ~ mpg + cal + disp + ....., data=mtcars)
```

There are over 50 variables in the dataframe.
I have tried

```
lm(mtcars$make ~ mtcars[, make])
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are trying to predict make from all the other factors.  Make is the row.name and not a factor.  But I think this code gives you what you are looking for, but to predict mpg instead of make.

```
lm(formula=mpg ~ . , data=mtcars)
```

The period stands for all other factors in the data frame.